# "The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception" when using PowerShell in C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I use an Cmdlet Powershell in C# with `System.Management.Automation` and when I execute my program I have the error :

> "The type initializer for
> 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception"

If you have any solution to resolved my problem ?
Thank you

Here is my code :

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript($"Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity '{prenomPointNom}' -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString '82ZH~U.!+3c2k)Cnn8Jdg?27H' -AsPlainText -Force)");
    PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
    if (PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ErrorRecord error in PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erreur : " + error.Exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with `PowerShell.Create(InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2())` to avoid loading the diagnostics module by default